# How can I call OnvalueChanged in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to add page ==> Like tab bar

I want to add like 2 pages - in this SegmentsBar...

How can I achieve it?

this is my code ---

[[image][image]

```
  final _segments = <String, String>{
    'freelancher': 'Freelancer',
    'employer': 'Employer',
  };
  var _value = 'freelancher';





                        AdvancedSegment(
                        sliderOffset: 5,
                        sliderColor: Colors.white,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.white24,
                        shadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.transparent,
                          ),
                        ],
                        activeStyle: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: AppTheme.medium,
                          color: AppTheme.primaryColor,
                        ),
                        inactiveStyle: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: AppTheme.medium,
                          color: AppTheme.white,
                        ),
                        itemPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 45,
                          vertical: 10,
                        ),
                        segments: _segments,
                        controller: _advanceC,
                        onValueChanged: (value) {
                          _value == value ? ChatPage() : ProfilePage();
                        },
                        value: _value,
                      ),
```

I need help please.

Thanks Buddy.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is AdvancedSegment, use instead [AnimatedPositioned](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hC3s2YdtWt8)

```
onValueChanged:
              (value) {
            setState(() {
              _value == value ? ChatPage() : ProfilePage();
            });
          }
```